# How to make footnotes left-right and the numbers in English in Persian documents?

Tags: xetex, footnotes, xepersian

The document is compiling in Xelatex and the whole document is Persian using the package xepersian. The footnotes are all in English but they are aligned right and the numbers are persian. I want the footnotes to be aligned at the left side of the document and the numbers of them to be in English. Note that just the numbers at the bottom of the page should be in English, the numbers referring them in the text should be Persian.

Comment: Since you have a response below that seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). If it does not answer your question, please consider adding some more information how the answer could be improved to suit your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `\LTRfootnote` command to set the footnote align from left to right. However, in terms of numbers, such a command does not change the numbers to Latin form.

Answer (score 2):

use ‍`پانویس` and `زیرنویس`

for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
‫یک مثال از پانویس\پانویس{left to right} و یک مثال از زیرنویس\زیرنویس{از راست به چپ}
\end{document}
```

[image: pdf]

Comment: Maybe you could expand that with some TeX code. A complete minimal example is usually more helpful.

Comment: `زیرنویس` and `پانویس` is commands of `xepersian`.

Comment: Yes, I figured that from the backslashes ;-) But it is still no complete minimal example, and that is what I meant with "some TeX code".

Comment: This solution seems not working when we use `\documentclass{report}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\parindent 1em
   \noindent\hbox to 1em{}% if you want to indent footnote text you can change the width of the hbox (e.g. \hbox to 2em{})
   \llap{\if@RTL\else\latinfont\fi\@thefnmark)\,\,}#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ptext[1]\footnote{\ptext[1]}\LTRfootnote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```